# "ac" class laptop NIC vs "n" class wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

If a laptop has a 802.11ac network card and the only available wifi is 802.11n, will the laptop be able to communicate with the "n" class wifi and connect to the Internet?

Thank you.

Comment: All on 5GHz? Or is this a dual-band network card?

Comment: I live in a nursing facility and have no access to the networking equipment. They also do not provide any user/customer/tech support of any kind. I'm sorry, but I can't answer that question.

Comment: I misread your question. I'm comparing three laptops. The description of the NIC says dual band on one, the other two just say 2x2 wifi. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Most likely they will all support n on both 2.4GHz and 5GHz.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is certainly a load off my mind. It looks like Spiff agrees with you.

Comment: WiFi standards are nearly always backwards compatible. That is, a wireless card in a laptop that supports AC should be able to connect to even a G-class wireless network. This is not always true the other way around though, as an AC wireless network may be configured NOT to broadcast or accept connections from a system that only supports a older wireless standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It seems to be a *de facto* standard that 802.11ac network cards support not only 802.11n and 802.11a in 5GHz, but also 802.11n, 802.11g, 802.11b, and, for that matter, 802.11-1997 DSSS, in 2.4GHz.

Comment: Thank you very much for that very detailed and very helpful answer.